# CloudFront HTTP/2 slower (high TTFB) than HTTP/1.1

Tags: https, cloud, optimization, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

My site was running on HTTP/1.1 with CloudFront at front, Webpagetest reports the load time usually at 2 seconds. Yesterday I enabled HTTP/2 (and SSL) on CloudFront, expecting to see an improvement. The result is, on the opposite, it becomes slower.

The load time is now around 3 seconds (tested via Webpagetest with different locations). The report shows most assets receive a big increase on TTFB comparing with HTTP/1.1. A 3KB image had **250ms** TTFB before, with HTTP/2, it becomes **750ms**.

Any advice?

---

Here are Webpagetest reports, if it helps

HTTP/1.1 https://www.webpagetest.org/result/180518_QY_4ecdf2626af50c5451dedddfbed2aef4/3/details/#waterfall_view_step1

HTTP/2 https://www.webpagetest.org/result/180519_TQ_cb737ae6e67b06da503d34d8d17d2e3a/3/details/#waterfall_view_step1

Comment: Your overall load time is _faster_ on HTTP/2, except for the fonts you are loading from external sites. It may have been a fluke. Try running the tests again.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, tested it again and got 2.9/3.2/2.8s, how do you tell overall load time is HTTP/2 faster?

Comment: I think it's expected. TTFB will be larger with SSL because client and server will have to negotiate a secure channel. Also read this: https://blog.cloudflare.com/ttfb-time-to-first-byte-considered-meaningles/

Comment: @SergeyKovalev, too bad, my goal is to reduce the load time to less than 2s, I almost did it with HTTP/1.1 (average 2.1s), it seems I have to go back to HTTP/1.1 and look for another way to optimize

Comment: @Edward, your comparison should be between HTTP/1.1 over TLS (explicit), and HTTP/2 over TLS (implicit).   It isn't meaningful as you have done it here, because you really shouldn't even be considering *not* using HTTPS, which seems to be what you're doing in the 1.1 test.  Compare using https with 1.1 and you should see a more meaningful comparison.